# Why cannot my API access another schema?

Tags: mysql, c, schema, c-api

When I query

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS;
```

it returns this error:

> `CODE[1146] MSG[Table 'EmailRecord.PARTITIONS' doesn't exist]`.

It works fine with the current schema, but I can't access any other schema.

I managed to access other schema in the workbench.

- Mysql version: *`5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`*
- C api: *`mysql/mysql.h`*
- Current schema: *`EmailRecord`*

Comment: do you mean `information_schema.partitions`?

Comment: YES. information_schema

Comment: And does it work with that?

Comment: No working in C API, but works in workbeach.

Comment: It should work, can you provide the failing code?

Comment: mysql_query(_conn, "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS;"); and failed. as long as I access other schema with ".", it will actually access current schema.

Comment: Try to remove the semicolon at the end of the query inside the query string and see if it works then

Comment: Tried, same result..

Comment: I think, the problem is out of scope what you show here, you will probably need to provide more context for a helpful answer. The message is exactly what you would expect when performing the query `SELECT * FROM PARTITIONS` while using the database EmailRecord.

Comment: GOT IT,  Remove MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT  when mysql_real_connect(). thanks Ctx.

Comment: I tried to show you how formatting and choosing proper title could enhance your question.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved and should be posted as an answer:

OP solution is :

> ## Remove parameter `MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT` when `mysql_real_connect()`

Too bad we don't have more source to chew on and help others, like e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188799/looping-mysql-real-connect-or-what), [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1456878/6019417)...